# Javascript tree view visualizer for say "call graphs"

Tags: javascript, treeview

I'm trying to build a callgraph (or let's say callstack) using Javascript.

Given something like (indented)

| FuncA

| FuncB

| FuncC

JsTree is something like this .. but I was hoping for something more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You could customize the looks of your jsTree by creating your own theme. Still it's a library for displaying trees, and the basic output structure stays more or less the same.

You might also take a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). As you can see in the demos you can do quite pretty stuff with it, though it's probably gonna take you more work to get it done.